# how to make a discord bot send a message every 20 or so minutes?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've got a discord bot and I want him to send random messages from a list every 20-30 minutes. I've survived off of youtube tutorials, reddit, and stack overflow because I don't really know python, but I haven't found anything specifically *for* this.

I have checked out multiple other questions from other people and, I have tried them, but they all included channel ids. I just want the bot to send it to the general channel instead of anything specific. this is what I got currently. any help would be appreciated. thank you!

```
@tasks.loop(hours=1.0)
async def send_message()
    channel = client.get_channel(channel id here)
     with open("quotes.txt", "r") as f:
        randomresponse=f.readlines()
        response=random.choice(randomresponse)
    @client.event
    async def on_ready()
    send_message.start()
```

Comment: If the approaches you found with channel ids work, why can't you just obtain the channel id for the general channel?

Answer (score 1):

The `guild.system_channel` attribute often points to the default channel where system messages are sent

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(minutes=30.0)  # I'm setting 30 minutes but you can set it to whatever you want.
async def send_message():
    with open("quotes.txt", "r") as f:
        randomresponse = f.readlines()
        response = random.choice(randomresponse)

    for guild in client.guilds:
        await guild.system_channel.send(response)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    send_message.start()  # You start the task here.

client.run('your-bot-token')
```